# Query performance Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

We have made a console application that it will update y column on the table b. Running this query on the server, it is pretty slow and i can not find out why. The table t size is 21 GB, table size of l is 13 GB.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.x,
                a.y 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.x = b.x 
-- x is uuid that we use on both tables
WHERE b.y IS NULL
  AND a.y IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 500;
```

What i have tried so far is ;

1. creating index with where statement on both tables like this

   create index idx_name
   on b(x)
   where (y IS NULL);

   create index idx_name
   on a(x)
   where (y IS NOT NULL);
2. Used group_by instead of distinct
3. Tried joining smallest to bigger table

Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Add execution plan. From what you describe: it looks like you did not tried to achieve `Index Only Scan`. Look for option `INCLUDE` in `CREATE INDEX`. I suppose `CREATE INDEX idx_name on a(x) INCLUDE (y) WHERE (y IS NOT NULL)` could achieve that

Comment: Explain analyze was taking too much time to return result too - It still tries since 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

Try creating these two multicolumn [*covering* indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html).

```
CREATE INDEX y_x_index ON a(y,x);
CREATE INDEX x_y_index ON b(x,y);
```

I'm guessing that the first index will help with these things:

1. Finding `a.y IS NOT NULL` rows.
2. Retrieving `a.x` to use for joining
3. Handling the SELECT DISTINCT deduplicating. The index is in an appropriate order to just scan for that purpose.
4. Avoiding any need to look in the main table, but instead using the index (that is what *covering* means).

The second index will help with

1. Retrieving `b.x` to use for joining.
2. Finding `b.y IS NULL`.
3. Avoiding any need to look in the main table, but instead using the index.

You might try switching the order of the columns in the second index and see if it's faster.

And, **pro tip**: Be aware that a LIMIT clause without an ORDER BY clause gives postgreSQL permission to return an unpredictable (non-deterministic) set of rows. If you want a predictable 500 rows put in `ORDER BY a.y, a.x`. The columns are seemingly reversed in that clause to match the index. `a.y` has to be first in the index or it won't be useful for matching `a.y IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Ty. I will try those but didnt i make it more specific when i used where statement in my indexes? I also checked `pg_stat_all_tables` to see if there were any dead tuples for both tables but no, there was not.